# Problems with while loops

Tags: java

I'm working on a project at the moment that's building a digitised version of a board game, and i'm having an issue with a while loop thats not doing as i expected.

Basically, **if** the player has **1 stone** left in his/her hand, and the next pit is **not** empty, they pick up the next pits stones and continue doing so, until **the next pit is empty**.

Now, my code continues **while** the next pit is empty and **while** one stone is remaining in their hand, however, it doesn't pick up the next pits stones if it isn't empty, it just adds one until the next pit **is** empty.

So my code is almost there, just not quite. So i'm looking for some help to improve the current code (a big comment above the code that needs work).

Let me know if the explanation is poor, i'll do my best to re-write it.

Cheers

```
while(hand == 1 && pit.next.stones != 0 && pit.next.pit == false) {
    int stones = pit.next.stones;
    for(int i = stones; i >= 1; i--) {
        hand++;
    }
    while(Hand >= 1 && pit.next.stones != 0) {
        hand--;
        addPieces(pit.next);
        pit = pit.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: This part `pit.next.pit == false` is strange. First this object is not a boolean so it's strange to compare it to a boolean. Then if ever it was a boolean, just do `!pit.next.pit` instead of `pit.next.pit == false`.

Comment: @vincrichaud it is a boolean, member of MancalaPit. But the naming could be better..

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the rules of Mancala, I don't think you are supposed to do that when you 1 stone left in your hand. If your last stone lands in an empty pit on your side, you steal the stones from the adjacent pit and add them (along with your one) to the scoring pit.

Comment: @Tobb Yes, i understand that. However this is for some coursework and our lecturer has 'jazzed up' the rules, so we don't blatantly copy other mancala games out there.

Comment: So if the last stone lands on a non-empty pit, you "start over" with the stones of this pit (adding one to the next and next and so on), and repeat this whole process until the last stone lands in an empty pit?

Comment: Exactly! My code repeats itself, just doesn't pick up the next pits stones and moves them, it rather adds one onto each pit until the next pit is empty.

Comment: If you have a method that does the regular flow of the game, adding a stone to each pit, you could add a check at the end of this flow, and if you "land" in a pit that has stones, just let the method call itself with this pit as a starting point.

Comment: I think i understand what you mean @Tobb. I've attached the main flow of the program, can you show me what you mean with that? Because i'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having mutli-nested loops. You should probably just update the stones in hand and stones in the pit and let the main loop continue as normal since the main loop is just the main game logic loop: grab stones, drop in pits, grab more stones and repeat?, ???, profit!

Eg:

Instead of:

```
while(hand >= 1 && pit.next != null) {
    // ...
    while (hand == 1 && pit.next.stones != 0 && pit.next.pit == false) {
        int stones = pit.next.stones;
        for (int i = stones; i >= 1; i--) {
            hand++;
        }
        while (hand >= 1 && pit.next.stones != 0) {
            hand--;
            addPieces(pit.next);
            pit = pit.next;
        }
    }
```

do something like:

```
while(hand >= 1 && pit.next != null) {
    // ...
    if(hand == 1 && pit.next.stones > 0 && pit.next.pit == false) {
        // update stones in hand
        hand += pit.next;
        // update stones in pit
        pit.next.stones = 0;
    }
    // let main loop continue
}
```

*(Note: I'm not 100% on the rules you are going for, just tried to follow what you said)*

Comment: That doesn't work. When i input a pit that player one wants to use, the flow of the game stops... Thanks for your help though

Comment: Sorry, it does work, i had the order of the code wrong. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @JimmyNeedles Awesome! glad I could help.